# why kafkaitemReader is always including last offset record of previous job run in the new job execution?

Tags: spring-batch

I am using spring batch kafkaItemReader in a job which is executed on a fixed delay of 10 seconds. Once the job with a chunk size of 1000 is completed, spring scheduler re-submits the same job again after a delay of 10 seconds. I am observing that KafkaReader is always including the last offset record in the subsequent job executions. Suppose, in the first job execution, records are processed from offset 1-1000, in my next job execution I am expecting kafkaItemReader to pick records from 1001 offset. But, in the next execution, kafkaItemReader is picking it up from offset 1000 (which is already processed).

Adding code blocks

//Job is getting submitted with scheduled task scheduler with below parameters

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" fixed-delay="5000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

//Job Parameters for each submission

String dateParam = new Date().toString();
JobParameters param =
new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", dateParam).toJobParameters

//Below is the kafkaItemReader configuration

```
@Bean
public KafkaItemReader<String, String> kafkaItemReader() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
    props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    Map<TopicPartition,Long> partitionOffset = new HashMap<>();

    return new KafkaItemReaderBuilder<String, String>()
            .partitions(0)
            .consumerProperties(props)
            .name("customers-reader")
            .saveState(true)
            .pollTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .topic("")
            .partitionOffsets(partitionOffset)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step kafkaStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,ItemWriter testItemWriter,KafkaItemReader kafkaItemReader) throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("kafkaStep")
            .chunk(10)
            .reader(kafkaItemReader)
            .writer(testItemWriter)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job kafkaJob(Step kafkaStep,JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("kafkaJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(kafkaStep)
            .build();
}
```

Am i missing some config which is causing this behaviour? I don't see this behaviour if i stop and re-run the application, it picks the offset properly in this case.

Comment: Does this mean the next run is off by one record? Please share your code, we need to see how you define and run your job instances (ie identifying job parameters) and how the reader is configured.

Comment: I have added code blocks to show the configuration, It is not off by one record, it is processing a duplicate record every time, the last record which was processed in previous job run is processed again in the next job run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running a new job instance on each shcedule (by using a different date as an identifying job parameter), but your reader is a singleton bean. This means it will be reused for each run without being reinitialized with the correct offset. You can make it step-scoped to have a new instance of the reader for each run:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public KafkaItemReader<String, String> kafkaItemReader() {
   ...
}
```

This will give you the same behaviour as if you restart the application, which you said fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, it resolved my problem. Now reader is working as expected. It is picking data from the correct offset.